# Evaluation of limit using Riemann Integration

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

Lets say we need to compute the below limit :
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{3}{n}\left[1+\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+3}}+\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+6}}+\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+9}}+\ldots+
\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+3(n-1)}}\right]
$$

> My procedure is shown below :.
> $$=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{3}{n}\left[\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+3 \times 0}}+\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+3 \times 1}}+\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+3 \times 2}}\right. ...\\
> =\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{3}{n}\left[\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \sqrt{\frac{n}{n+3r}}\right]
>  = \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} 3\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+3\left(\frac{r}{n}\right)}}.$$
> After this i gets that this is of normal form : $$\lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}\sum_{0}^{n-1} f(a+\frac{(b-a)h}{n})\frac{(b-a)}{n}$$ , where h varies from $0$ to $n-1$ , from here by comparing i get $b-a = 3$ , $a=1$ and $3/n$ changes to $dx$ , $3r/n$ changes to $x$ , and $b = 4$ , so this converts to integral
> $$\int_{1}^{4} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}} d x=2 \sqrt{5}-2 \sqrt{2}$$ but answer given is 2 , what error i did ?

Comment: By definition of Riemann sums, you have $$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{3}{n} \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+3\left(\frac{r}{n}\right)}} = 3\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+3x}} dx$$

Comment: If you set $a=1$ then your $f$  should be $1/\sqrt{x}$, not $1/\sqrt{1+x}$. If you set $a=0$, then your $f$ would be correct.

Comment: But is my expression for expressing integral from a to b f(x)dx in that normal limit form which i got not correct ?

Comment: I am just comparing from that , thats what i want to know whats going wrong there

Comment: Oh yes you are right but why i dont get it @NinadMunshi ? a should be 1 isnt from the 
comparison of  f(a+h(b-a)/n) = f(1+3x/n) ?

Comment: Exactly, read what you wrote again and pattern match the expressions

Comment: Oh i see from coverting limit to integral we will just take the h(b-a)/n part and says its x , not the whole a+h(b-a)/n as x , this was my mistake right ? @NinadMunshi but though i still have a little bit confusion , if you may provide the part i am making mistake i will accept that as answer

Comment: Your mistake was the exact opposite of what you just said. You took the smaller part and said it was $x$, when the whole part should have been $x$

Comment: Okay got it but you said a=0 also we can take but why ?? I mean from comparison we are getting a= 1 isnt ?

Comment: Or there is another form in which the limit can be compared @NinadMunshi where a= 0 makes sense?